# Select Empty admin page django

Tags: python, django

I have written a model, where class `Actor` has a `ForeignKey` to the `Movie` class. My question is, why is the select-html-object "Movie" in the admin page `Actor` empty (I had added movies)?

[image]

models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model) :
    code = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u""

class Actor(models.Model) :
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def __unicode__(self):
    return u""
```

I'm trying to fix that using the class `ActorAdmin` but I don't know why this does not work?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Movie
from .models import Actor

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Movie)


class ActorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Actor
    list_display = ['name', 'get_title',]

    def get_title(self, obj):
        return obj.movie.title


admin.site.register(Actor,ActorAdmin)
```

Comment: Those are not empty, the text to represent the objects is.

Answer (score 3):

Because of this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u""
```

if you add:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

you will see them there.